# u' admin' is not a registered namespace in django

Tags: python, django

I am writing an application for django admin and everything seems to be going well till I used `admin:` in url on my templates and I got error `u' admin' is not a registered namespace` I am using the latest django version as at **october 2017**

**html**

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %} {% load staticfiles %}
{% block extrastyle %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static " css/admin.css " %}" />
{% endblock %}
{% block title %} Order {{ order.id }} {{ block.super }} {% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <a href="{% url " admin:index " %}">Home</a> &rsaquo;
  <a href="{% url " admin:orders_order_changelist " %}">Orders</a>&rsaquo;
  <a href="{% url " admin:orders_order_change " order.id %}">Order {{ order.id }}</a> &rsaquo; Detail
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**admin.py**

```
def order_detail(obj):
    return '<a href="{}">View</a>'.format(
        reverse('orders:admin_order_detail', args=[obj.id]))

order_detail.allow_tags = True
```

**urls.py**

`url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),`

**app urls.py**

`url(r'^admin/order/(?P<order_id>\d+)/$', views.admin_order_detail, name='admin_order_detail'),`

further codes would be provided on request

Comment: You shouldn't have the leading and trailing spaces, for example change `" admin:index "` to `"admin:index"`

Comment: the error is `u' admin' is not a registered namespace`

Comment: works Thanks. post it as an answer so that I can mark as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the leading and trailing whitespace. For example you should replace

```
{% url " admin:index " %}
```

with

```
{% url "admin:index" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your urls.py, you use `name='admin_order_detail'` but in view you're looking for `"{% url " admin:index " %}"`.
So, to make your code work, you have to use defined in urls.py name, like:

`"{% url "admin_order_detail" %}"` or `"{% url "admin.your path" %}"`

Comment: The name admin_order_detail also appears. I just shortened the html to include some urls because I can’t include all the html code (stackoverflow rule)